# Как в PhpStorm отключить Remote Edit?

Tags: phpstorm

Как в PhpStorm отключить Remote Edit?

Remote Edit - это когда при клике по файлу в Remote Host (справа) открывается удаленное редактирование.

В старых версиях это неудобной функции не было.

Comment: Ну скачайте файлы и редактируйте их. Зачем вы открываете Удаленное редактирование вообще? :)